# JFreeChart: Candlestick chart with different x-axis?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to draw a candlestick chart with the x-axis being of the type number/integer, instead of time? Currently i'm using `ChartFactory#createCandlestickChart` which takes an OHLCDataset, which uses a timestamps for the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ChartFactory::createCandlestickChart`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createCandlestickChart(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jfree.data.xy.OHLCDataset,boolean)) uses a [`DateAxis`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) [internally](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1861), which sees each data item's `Date` as the number of milliseconds since the epoch. As a result, you can

- Specify the desired format in `setDateFormatOverride()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20setDateFormatOverride), or
- Use a `NumberAxis` in your own factory, perhaps modeled on the one [cited](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1861), or simply substitute a `NumberAxis`:

  ```
    XYPlot xyplot = chart.getXYPlot();
    NumberAxis domain = new NumberAxis();
    domain.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    domain.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getInstance());
    xyplot.setDomainAxis(domain);
  ```

[image: Axis image]